# How to represent a single cell in minitab 16?

Tags: statistics, addition, cell

How to represent a single cell in minitab 16?
There is C1, C2 ... as column, and 1, 2 ,3 .. as rows...i tried like excel but dint work
i need to do single row statistics...so any idea?

Answer (score 0):

C1[1] would be the first cell in column C1, C1[2] is the second cell, etc.